# Resizing JFrame and components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm currently working on a Java GUI Memory game for an assignment and I have just about everything figured out except for one part. I cannot get the all the components to fit inside the JFrame without some weird behavior and a very ugly looking game. The game consists of a keyboard, a grid whose size depends on the difficulty (3 x 4 for easy, 4 x 7 for medium, and 7 x 8 for hard) and a turn box on the left side of the JFrame (BorderLayout.WEST) that shows the turn number. I will attach photos of the 3 frames and also the constructors for the grid, turn box, and JFrame.
[image: This is the easy game]

This is the easy game.

[image]

This is the medium game.

[image]

This is the hard game.

Here is the constructor for the turn box:

```
    public TurnBox(MemoryFrame view, MemoryModel model, int width) //extends JPanel
{
    this.model = model;
    this.letterWidth = 64;
    this.insets = new Insets(0, 6, 6, 6); 
    this.topMargin = 0;
    int wordWidth = (letterWidth + insets.right) * model.getColumns(); //# of columns in the game
    this.leftMargin = (width - wordWidth)/2;
    int height = (letterWidth + insets.bottom) * model.getRows() //# of rows in the game
            + 2 * topMargin;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.turn = buildRectangle();
}


private Rectangle buildRectangle()
{
    
    int x = 50;
    int y = topMargin;
    
    Rectangle turn = new Rectangle(x, y, letterWidth,
            letterWidth);
    
    return turn;
}
```

Here is the constructor for the grid:

```
    public MemoryBoard(MemoryFrame view, MemoryModel model, int width)
{
    this.model = model;
    this.action = new KeyBoardButtonAction(view, model);
    this.topMargin = 0;
    this.letterWidth = 64;
    this.insets = new Insets(0, 6, 6, 6); //Distance between squares

    int wordWidth = (letterWidth + insets.right) * model.getColumns();
    this.leftMargin = (width - wordWidth) / 2;
    int height = (letterWidth + insets.bottom) * model.getRows()
            + 2 * topMargin;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.grid = buildGrid();
}

private Rectangle[][] buildGrid() { //Part 3 here, change size of grid
    Rectangle[][] grid = new Rectangle[model.getRows()][model.getColumns()];
    //Rectangle[][] grid = new Rectangle[7][6];

    int x = leftMargin;
    int y = topMargin;

    for (int row = 0; row < model.getRows(); row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < model.getColumns(); column++) {
            grid[row][column] = new Rectangle(x, y, letterWidth,
                    letterWidth);
            x += letterWidth + insets.right;
        }
        x = leftMargin;
        y += letterWidth + insets.bottom;
    }

    return grid;
}
```

And here is the constructor for the JFrame:

```
    public MemoryFrame(MemoryModel model, StartingFrame s)
{
    this.model = model;
    this.start = s;
    this.keyboardPanel = new KeyboardPanel(this, model);
    int width = keyboardPanel.getPanel().getPreferredSize().width;
    this.board = new MemoryBoard(this, model, width);
    this.turn = new TurnBox(this, model, width);
    
    this.frame = initializeFrame();
}

private JFrame initializeFrame()
{
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Memory Game");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
    frame.setResizable(false);
    //frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            shutdown();
        }
    });
    
    frame.add(createTitlePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(turn, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Change according to difficulty
    frame.add(keyboardPanel.getPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    System.out.println("Frame size: " + frame.getSize());
    
    return frame;
    
}
```

I apologize for such a long post but I really cannot figure this out. I have tried making the JFrame large and then using .pack() but that doesn't seem to do anything. Other changes I have tried to make is attempting to get rid of the width parameter and using concrete integers, which aligns the grid but deletes the turn box. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: Why aren't you putting the turn box, grid, and buttons in separate `JPanels`?  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: 1) I have no idea if you code is actually using Swing components or doing custom painting.  2) Why is the width of the "turn" panel based on the width of the "keyboard" panel? 3) Don't use setPreferredSize(). If you manually need to control the size of the panel for some reason then you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method. Then you pass parameters to the class such as row, columns, cell size. These parameters will be used by the getPreferredSize() method to dynamically calculate the size.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The turn box and grid classes are both children of the JPanel class, so they are JPanel objects. Would it be more helpful to put them in a new JPanel object instead?

Comment: @camickr, GilbertLeBlanc I figured it out with your advice! Thank you both for your help!